# Discord.py How to detect links posted by other people?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I want to detect links posted in discord by other discord users so I can later check all the links that get posted. Right now I have coded everything and I don't understand why it's not working.

If I post a link it detects it and shows properly but if someone else does it doesn't detect it, dunno what I can do to fix this issue.

```
token = "xxxxxxx"

client = discord.Client()
    
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    urls = re.findall("(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'.,<>?«»“”‘’]))?", message.content)
    if urls:
        print (f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Link(s) Found:")
        for x in range(len(urls)):
            print(urls[x])


client.run(token)
```

if I don't include the bot=False I get an error saying invalid token but if I do include it I get no errors but I also can't detect what other users post.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you need to do to fix this. First off, you need to remove the `bot=False`, it makes you a whole ton more suspicious. The reason this hasn’t worked for you in the past in your use of `discord.Client`, you should be instead using [`commands.Bot()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bots).

Comment: but commands.Bot() would require me to create a bot myself and have it join the server. Not what I intended to do >.<

Comment: If you're trying to make a self-bot, all you're going to end up doing is getting yourself banned.

Comment: I wont because all im doing is recording the links I'm not doing anything else harmful

Comment: Using a self-bot isn’t allowed, and it most likely never will be allowed. It’s a violation of the Discord TOS, regardless of how you’re using it.